# Change the colour of a cell that has the maximum value

Tags: vba, excel, colors, max

I'm trying to recolour the cell with the highest value in a range, but whatever method I'm using, there always seems to be one combination that does not work. I'm not rely used to VBA. What I've tried the last is:

```
Sub HLF()
  Dim HLF As Range
  Set HLF = WorksheetsFunction.Max(Range("H2:H7"))
  Range("HLF").Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
End Sub
```

It seems that the 'Set' and 'Max' function don't go together. My basic programming logic says that a normal 'Range' should be replaceable by a function that finds a range, but apparently Excel says not. I've also tried by selecting the cell and using 'ActiveCell' instead of 'Range' to color the cell, but a function and select don't seem to go together either. Other supposed solutions seem overly complicated for such a small task.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Max` will return a *value* from your column.  This won't, by itself, give you a cell, which is required for a range.  What you can do is a small workaround, see below:

```
Sub test()
Dim HLF As Range, finalHLF
Dim maxNum As Double
Set HLF = Range("H2:H7")
maxNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(HLF)

finalHLF = HLF.Find(what:=maxNum, lookat:=xlWhole).Address
Range(finalHLF).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

This will find your max value, then using that max value, will search in the determined range (in your example, `H2:H7` for that max value, then return that cell's address.  Then you can continue on with the `.Color`, using the `.Address`).

But, as has also been suggested, Conditional Formatting might be your safest bet - as it's easy, and doesn't require the use of macros.  But try the above and let me know if you have any questions!

Edit: As @asongtoruin pointed out, the above only will highlight one of the max values, so if there are multiple cells of the same max value, only one will be highlighted.  The below code will highlight all max values:

```
Sub test()
Dim HLF As Range, cel As Range
Dim maxNum As Double

Set HLF = Range("H2:H7")
maxNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(HLF)

For Each cel In HLF
    If cel.Value = maxNum Then
        cel.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: If the maximum appeared more than once, would this not only return the first instance of the max value? Might be worth using a `For` loop for all cells in `HLF` instead of `Find` to ensure you catch every instance of the maximum.

Comment: @asongtoruin - good call! I'll edit my post.  (Although your point also exemplifies why using Conditional Formatting might be the best option - it'd catch all such instances of the max number).

Comment: Thank you! The method works, although I had to specify the sheet at both 'Range' commands to get it to work. I did use the first suggestion. Since the numbers are ratio's between 10 figure numbers the chance of two numbers being the same is very small.

Comment: @BerndKeuning - Happy to help! If it worked, do you mind marking as the answer?  Also, just to make sure, if you're using `Range(cells(),Cells())` instead of `Range("A1:A10")`, then specify the sheet before Range *and* cells, ie. myWS.Range(myWS.Cells(1,1),myWS.cells(10,1))`.

Answer (score 2):

`Max` doesn't return the location of the maximum value - it simply tells you what the maximum value is. In this case, your `Set HLF = WorksheetsFunction.Max(Range("H2:H7"))` is trying to set the range `HLF` to equal the value of the maximum in your range. This, I think, is why it's throwing out an error.

As @Scott Craner suggests, you can do this through Conditional Formatting fairly easily - select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" in conditional formatting, set it to apply to the range `H2:H7` and set the rule to be `=H2=MAX($H$2:$H$7)`. The advantage of this is it will update as soon as your values do.

Comment: to add more clarity to `to equal the value of the maximum in your range` ... `when its expecting a valid Excel range object because it's declared as Range`